# How can I import data from SAP Table to an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp

I am new to Excel VBA.
I don't know how to get the data from SAP table to Excel sheet.

The query is.
I have one Excel sheet containing 10 fields.
Basing on `pcode` field (in Excel), `PL` will be imported from SAP table.

Example

```
ID | name  | pcode | PL (from SAP)
---+-------+-------+-----------------
1  | kiran | 1234  | 
2  | karan | 5001  |
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot access SAP data from VBA. Yet, you can export the data from SAP (through SM30 or any query transaction) and then use the exported data in Excel. Please edit you question to be clearer about what you really intend to do.

Comment: Hi AFAIK, Actually i want to retrive the data from SAP to Excel Sheet. The 'Pcode' value matches with SAP table then the PL value will be retrieved from SAP and paste it in Excel spread sheet.The Pcode, PL columns are in SAP table (one). Thank u for your reply

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to map the values extracted from SAP with some other values in Excel? Then you should use a `VLOOKUP` formula.

Comment: You are right, i thought it is not possible through vlookup because we need to login into SAP database first. If possible please will u provide the VBA code for me. Thank u for u advise and help.

Comment: If you know what are you doing and you are very carefull you can access sap database directly using ODBC/JDBC from excel (oracle, sql server, db2...), but be aware not to make any change (always acces them read only)because you can corrupt your SAP system...

Comment: not yet got the solution

Comment: I have done a little bit of automation in Excel to SAP recently at work. Simple stuff but I was using the scripting in SAP. From what I understand you might have significant issues if you don't have strong API access to SAP. I don't and am not able to get it enabled so I had to use scripting which means running transactions and implementing logic that way to get the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of documentation online for writing into Excel sheets from VB, as there is a lot of documentation for reading SQL table data into VB, you can google these things and find what you need.
Something you might not find through Google is how to track down the tables you actually require.
SAP data all comes from tables that I like to call "Background" tables. Although SAP presents all the data in a nice format which is easy on the eyes, it is all actually just a set of big ugly SQL tables.
Lets say I want to extract all of the items that I have in stock (as far as SAP knows), then write this info into an excel sheet, here's where to begin:

Firstly TURN ON SYSTEM INFORMATION. To do this, press Ctrl + Shift + I (or go to View -> system information), now when you hover over a field, the bar at the bottom of the SAP screen will tell you all of the background information that you'll need to find the location of the data in SQL.

[image: Hover mouse somewhere and look here!]

When you hover your cursor over a field, the bar highlighted in this image should show something like this:

Manual [Form = 142 Item = 38 Pane = 1 Column = 14700021 Row = 1 Variable = 11 POR1,UomCode]

Here the parts we are interested are the "POR1, UomCode" Here, "POR1" will be the name of the SQL table which contains the data you're after, and "UomCode" is the column name.

This example was for a purchase order, but for item master data this information will be different, the table name will be OITM, with item details being held in ITM1.

And so you would contruct a SQL query which will bring through all the info you need from the tables, package it up into variables in whatever programming language you choose (I use VB.NET), then spit it out into Excel.

Hope this helped!

Comment: While I remember, DON'T DO ANYTHING EXCEPT SELECT THIS DATA!!! (Unless you really know what you're doing), inserting into here etc, can cause problems which SAP will not support you on.

Comment: I would further caution the OP by saying, if you aren't an expert at this, just use SAP's natural export functions, grab a .xls file as a data dump, and paste that into an Excel spreadsheet which formats your values as desired.